# theoretic modification to railgun base components

Tags: coil, electromagnetic

I just began researching rail guns and want to build one myself had a few ideas but the actual barrel gave me an idea I wasn't sure of. Can you construct a coil that produces an electromagnetic field using fiber optic wire and if so would it be more efficient than a copper coil? I'm considering 100v 33300uf aluminum capacitors and have yet to look into diodes. Teaching myself the basics and principles as I go.

Comment: Please add some formatting to your question, to make it a bit easier to read than being all one big paragraph. :)

Comment: Long story short can I make rods out of fiber optics to form a magnetic track

Comment: It seems you misunderstand how a [railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) works. The rails _must_ be conductive, and fiber optic cable is typically made of glass/plastic/rubber, none of which are particularly conductive. Also, railguns do not use copper coils. Perhaps you mean a [coilgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun)?

Answer (score 1):

Optical fiber is not wire. No current flows in optical fiber, so, no magnetic fields are created or destroyed (indeed, getting data signals through a lab full of nasty pulsed magnets intact was the first thing I ever used fiber optics for - at a whopping 9600 (or was it only 2400?) baud.)

I'll suggest MIT 6.002 (via open courseware, or open university or whatever they call it this week) as a nice solid course you can [get online for free.](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/)

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. You can't pass a meaningful electrical current through plastic/glass fiber optic lines, and any attempts to incite electric currents by forcing light to spiral are *not* likely to work on this scale.

In Long: Are you trying to build a railgun (2 conductor "rails" that force huge current through projectile, or through plasma behind projectile), or a coilgun (1 or more coils of wire that propel projectile by electromagnetic induction)? You'll definitely need to be sure which one you want to build before continuing.

Comment: I was proposing that the rails could be coils of fiber optics and wondered I'd the could hold/produce electromagnetism more efficiently toying with the idea of a single strand corkscrewed into the walls of a barrel forming a single circuit could produce significant force without chances of a short causing spot wields

Comment: Drawing, please.  I suspect that most people will have a difficult time visualizing what you have in mind.

Comment: This vase has the spiral design I was thinking but one continuous strand. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/87/9b/7d/879b7d789bd4e3e79abcc5b2de0595a9.jpg